# Como puedo hacer para que se sume automaticamente la cantidad de subtotales de una tabla al modificar un input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un listado de un carrito de compras, hasta el momento he podido hacer que se tome el valor de un input (lo cual seria la cantidad de productos a comprar) y se multiplique por el valor del producto, con esto puedo ir teniendo temporalmente unos subtotales, en ese orden de ideas como puedo hacer para sumar todos esos subtotales y que ese resultado se muestre a medida que voy cambiando la cantidad de productos de cada input, el desarrollo lo estoy haciendo con angular 10

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let prod of carritoCompras">
    <th colspan="7">{{prod.nombre}}</th>
    <td colspan="3">{{prod.precio | currency}}</td>
    <td colspan="1"><input #cant type="number" name="cantidad" value="1" min="0" max="100" step="1"
            style="height: 1.2rem; font-size: 0.7rem;" class="w-50 ml-2"
            onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" (change)="calcTotal()">
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="subt">{{prod.precio * cant.value | currency }}</td>
    <td colspan="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar del carrito">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-3" (click)="eliminaCart()"> X </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

este es el codigo de typeScript

```
    carritoCompras: any
    constructor() {
      this.carritoCompras = []  
    }
    //con esto se identifica el usuario para consultar los productos en su carrito de compras 
    this.consultaBackEnd.identificaUsuario(this.usuario._id).subscribe(res => {
      res.findUser.listaCompras.forEach(idProd => {
      //se hace una consulta en la base de datos para listar los detalles de cada producto del listado de compras
      this.consultaBackEnd.detalleProducto(idProd).subscribe(res=>{
      this.carritoCompras.push(res.prod)
    })
  });
```

Esta es la lo que tengo hasta el momento, la idea es que al modificar los input pueda tener la sumatoria total de todo el carrito automaticamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el total puedes hacer una función que recorra el arreglo de productos y sume la cantidad por precio de cada uno para obtener el total. En la plantilla puedes interpolar el valor devuelto por la función  `{{ actualizarTotal() }}`. En el ejemplo el input se vincula con la propiedad cantidad del producto, cuando el valor se actualiza el total lo hace también.

```
@Component({
      selector: "my-app",
      template: `
        <table border="1">
          <tr *ngFor="let producto of productos">
            <td>{{ producto.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ producto.precio }}</td>
            <td><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="producto.cantidad" /></td>
            <td>{{ producto.precio * producto.cantidad }}</td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ actualizarTotal() }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      `
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    
      productos: any[] = [
        {
          nombre: "lavadora",
          precio: 100,
          cantidad: 1
        },
        {
          nombre: "licuadora",
          precio: 50,
          cantidad: 2
        }
      ];
    
      actualizarTotal() {
        let total = 0;
    
        this.productos.forEach(p => {
          total += p.precio * p.cantidad;
        });
        
        return total;
      }
    }
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvfjv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Muchas gracias, era exactamente lo que estaba buscando y funciona perfecto